# How can I prevent my migration from overwriting existing nodes instead of using the source's (D7) NID

Tags: migrations

I have imported my content types from D7 to D9 using /upgrade for the complete migration and the data is all good. I then have a separate migration to import and convert my date fields and this works too, except that it overwrites all of the existing nodes instead of using their exiting NID or pulling it from the source again. Any ideas how to prevent this?

```
id: event_node
label: Event Nodes
migration_group: custom
source:
  plugin: d7_node
  target: event
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  bundle: event
process:
  nid: nid
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: event
  field_event_date:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: field_event_date
      process:
        value:
          -
            plugin: format_date
            from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
            to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
            source: value

        end_value:
          -
            plugin: format_date
            from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
            to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
            source: value2
        timezone:
          -
            plugin: default_value
            default_value: 'America/New_York'
        rrule:
          -
            plugin: get
            source: rrule
```

Comment: Remove all other fields except nid and date fields. It will map data to only those two fields leaving other fields untouched.

Comment: When I removed the other fields, specifically the "type" filed the imported runs but the date fields are not updated.

Comment: In source change target key to node_type. It will solve your issue

Comment: Don't forget to reimport the config

Comment: Check this file for reference https://drupal.slack.com/files/UBUGWVA3G/F02J5A3PZV3/d7_node_article_part_one.yml

Comment: Thank you for the tip but the target key is already set to the node type's machine name ("event").  And the plugin is d7:node - per your tip there is nothing for me to change.

Comment: No no, what i meant is remove the key target completely and add a new key node_type: event and try again

Comment: Thank you. I had actually realized that after posting. So the only thing under "Souce" is "node_type: event" but now I'm getting the error: "The "" plugin does not exist." - I looked at your example to compare but don't see the issue. I'll update my current YML in the original post.

Comment: Do one thing remove every thing from your yml and copy my yml to your yml and change names accordingly. And keep nid and add date field  and try to import. It will work

Comment: plugin: d7_node is needed dont delete it

Comment: Ugg, I tried your template but I think it's just too different of a scenario. I went back to my basic config and noticed that id specify the nid when running migrate-import that it updates the node correct but if I run it without so it just processes all of the event nodes then it resets their nids starting at nid 1. This works for a single specified NID:  drush migrate-import  event_node --update --idlist=5318

Comment: Seems you are doing something wrong. Ping me on Drupal slack will try to help you